# needs pagination due to Collection size 1,375 exceeds maximum size of 1,000.

Tags: pagination

I am encountering the said error above

```
<apex:page docType="html-5.0" standardController="Account" Extensions="StandingController">
<style type="text/css">
    body {background: #F3F3EC; padding-top: 15px}
</style>

<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock title="Search by AsOfDate" id="block" mode="edit">
        <apex:pageMessages />
        <apex:pageBlockSection >
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <apex:panelGroup >
                    <b>PartnerID: </b><apex:inputText title="Aff ID" id="searchText" value="{!SearchText}"/><p/>
                    <b>AsOfDate: </b><apex:input label="AsOfDate" type="date" id="AsOfDate" value="{!AsOfDate}"/> <p/>
                    <apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!search}" rerender="resultsBlock" status="status"/><p/>
                    <apex:commandButton value="Export results to Excel" action="{!export}"/><p/>
                    <!-- <apex:commandButton value="Export to Excel" action="{!Export}" rerender="resultsBlock" status="status"/><p/>-->
                </apex:panelGroup>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
        <apex:actionStatus id="status" startText="Searching... please wait..."/>
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Standing Status as of {!AsOfDate}" showHeader="true" id="resultsBlock" columns="2">
            <apex:pageBlockTable title="Status" value="{!searchResults}" var="o" rendered="{!NOT(ISNULL(searchResults))}">
                <apex:column headerValue="Name">
                    <apex:outputLink value="/{!o.Id}">{!o.Name}</apex:outputLink>
                </apex:column>                        
                   <!-- <apex:column value="{!o.AR_Number__c}"/>-->
                    <apex:column value="{!o.Partner_ID__c}"/>
    <apex:column >
     <apex:dataTable value="{!o.Standing_Status_History__r}" var="q">
        <apex:column headerValue="Status" value="{!q.Standing_Status_New__c}"/>                          
        <apex:column headerValue="Reason" value="{!q.Out_of_Standing_Reason_New__c}"/>                          
        <apex:column headerValue="Date" value="{!q.Change_Date__c}"/>              
     </apex:dataTable>
    </apex:column>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>

    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

Apex Class

```
public with sharing class StandingController {

private ApexPages.StandardController controller {get; set;}
public StandingController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

    //initialize the stanrdard controller
    this.controller = controller;
    this.a = (Account)controller.getRecord();
}

List<Profile> PROFILE = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Profile WHERE Id=:userinfo.getProfileId() LIMIT 1];
String MyProfileName = PROFILE[0].Name; 

public List<Account> accList =  [Select AR_Number__c, Partner_Id__c from Account where id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];
String ARNum = accList[0].AR_Number__c;
String PartnerID = accList[0].Partner_id__c;

// the text in the search box
public String SearchText {
    get {
        if (SearchText == null) 
            SearchText =  PartnerID;
        return SearchText;
    }
    set;
}


private Account a;
public List<Account> searchResults {get;set;}

// Set AsOfDate
public date AsOfDate {
    get {
        if (AsOfDate == null) 
            AsOfDate =  system.today();//'2016-12-01T00:00:00.000Z'  ; // prefill the serach box for ease of use
        return AsOfDate;   
    }
    set;
}

public String ProgramText {
    get {
        if (ProgramText == null) 
            ProgramText = 'SHOP';
        return ProgramText;   
    }
    set;
}



// Execute Search
public PageReference search() {

    if (searchResults == null) {
        searchResults = new List<Account>(); // init the list if it is null
    } else {
        searchResults.clear(); // clear out the current results if they exist
    }


    // Build Search Query
    //transient String qry = 'SELECT Id, Name, AR_Number__c ,Partner_ID__c ,  (select Standing_Status_New__c  , Change_Date__c, Out_Of_Standing_Reason_New__c ' +
    String qry = 'SELECT Id, Name, AR_Number__c ,Partner_ID__c ,  (select Standing_Status_New__c  , Change_Date__c, Out_Of_Standing_Reason_New__c ' +
        'from Standing_Status_History__r ' + 
        'where Change_Date__c < ' +
        String.ValueOf(AsOfDate) +'T00:00:00.000Z'+ 
        ' ORDER BY Change_Date__c DESC LIMIT 1) '+
        'from Account ' + 
        'where Type = \'U.S. Affiliate\' ' +
        'and status__c = \'Active\' ' +
        'and Partner_Id__c Like \'%'+SearchText+'%\' ';     

    system.debug('query: ' + qry);
    //Return results to VF Page
    searchResults = Database.query(qry);

    return null;
}

public PageReference export() 
{
    return page.StandingReportExport;
}

    /*
 //Boolean to check if there are more records after the present displaying records
public Boolean hasNext
{
    get
    {
        return con.getHasNext();
    }
    set;
} 
//Boolean to check if there are more records before the present displaying records
public Boolean hasPrevious
{
    get
    {
        return con.getHasPrevious();
    }
    set;
} 
//Page number of the current displaying records
public Integer pageNumber
{
    get
    {
        return con.getPageNumber();
    }
    set;
}
//Returns the previous page of records
public void previous()
{
    con.previous();
} 
//Returns the next page of records
public void next()
{
    con.next();
}
*/
```

}

Comment: You're not going to get worth while responses asking a question this way, you can use https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_ReadOnly.htm tho..

Comment: I tried using the readonly, the problem still occurs, but the other errors still, i'm now trying to use pagination instead still searching

Comment: the error when i used pagination and readonly is Maximum view state size limit (135KB) exceeded. Actual view state size for this page was 165.423KB

Comment: Then you could try and use transient variables.. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_keywords_transient.htm.  But unless someone has a easy pattern to copy and paste no one is going to build a pagination page for you.  Also I don't see anything crazy your code you may want to check your Where filters

Comment: I previously tried the transient unfortunately it affects the other pages.  i'm just creating pagination as of now..